# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined for simple JSON array

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function this way .

```
var responseinner = returnvalues(selectedeleemnt);

console.log(responseinner);
```

**displaying as Object**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(responseinner));
```

**displaying as** `[{"name":"Coke","image":"json_images/coke_can.jpg","type":["250ml","300ml"],"price":["50","60"]}]`

I tried all the ways of parsing this value

```
[{"name":"Coke","image":"json_images/coke_can.jpg","type":["250ml","300ml"],"price":["50","60"]}]
```

But always it throws the error as

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

I used JSON.parse , JSON.stringfy() . but none helped .

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseinner.type.length; i++) {

}
```

could anybody please help me

Comment: Why is JSON involved at all?

Comment: You need an index; `responseinner[0].type.length` to identify the object containing the `type` array you wish to examine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for(var i=0;i<responseinner.length;i++){
responseinner[i].type .... }`

Comment: Thank you very very much . i was really strugling with this .

Answer (score 1):

Your `responseinner` isn't an `Object` but an `Array` with only one element.

So, you'll have to use `responseinner[0].type.length`

If it was an object, it would have started with `{}` and not `[]`, with what arrays start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `of`

```js
for (let element of responseinner) {
    // do something../
    console.log(element.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse json with jquery:

```
  $.each($.parseJSON(responseinner), function(key,value){
        //do something
    });
```

*If responseinner is already formed as a json you don't need the $.parseJSON*

or

```
responseineer[0].name
responseineer[0].image
...
```

Json data comes into an array so get it's object with an index, so to access it: `responseineer[0]`

Answer (score 0):

try `test[0].type.length` you have an Object in an array of length 1 therefore you must first define the index location of the Object in the array which is trivial since the array has 1 defined index.

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseinner[0].type.length; i++) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for(var i=0;i

Its works fine but...how to assign to gridview in client side